# Can't run Insert and Select LAST_INSERT_ID() in the same query?

Tags: mysql

I am using node to connect to mysql and I need to run an insert and then immediately run a select last_insert_id().

```
insert into data_temp values (null, '{"test":{"id":12,"otherdata":"x","otherdata2":"y"}}');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

In mysql workbench this query works but gives me an error saying:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() )
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ')' at line 2  0.047 sec

It actually returns the correct id but because it is throwing an error on the last part node is catching the error.

Comment: update you question and add the data_temp  table schema please

Comment: Are you running this from PHP or whatever else?

Comment: Since I am using node mysql package it already grabs the last inserted id and grabbing it twice throws this error I guess. I solved this by using results.insertID from the mysql node library.

Comment: @jshill103 please post your solution? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your insert query you just missed to put the name of your **columns**

Do like this

```
insert into data_temp (`col1`, `col2`) values (null, '{"test":
{"id":12,"otherdata":"x","otherdata2":"y"}}'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

In place of `col1`and  `col2` put your columns name then it will work for you.