# How to insert last_insert_id in the same table and column within looping

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have table name routes with column like below

- id
- name
- master_id

What I wanna do is insert the first inserted_id into master_id with same value. This query will run within the loop like this example it runs 4 time. Example:

```
+-----+------+-----------+
| id  | name | master_id |
+-----+------+-----------+
| 625 |name_1|    625    |
| 626 |name_3|    625    |
| 627 |name_3|    625    |
| 628 |name_4|    625    |
```

My reference and what I've tried
[Can't run Insert and Select LAST_INSERT_ID() in the same query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982947/cant-run-insert-and-select-last-insert-id-in-the-same-query)?

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $array_length - 1; $i++){
   for($j = $i + 1; $j < $array_length; $j++){
     $select_last_inserted_id = $con->query("select LAST_INSERT_ID() as last_insert_id from routes");
     $last_insert_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_last_inserted_id);
     $routes = "insert into routes(name, master_id) values('$name',".$last_insert_id['last_insert_id'].")";
    }
}
```

My current result(wrong one)

```
+-----+------+-----------+
| id  | name | master_id |
+-----+------+-----------+
| 625 |name_1|    0      |
| 626 |name_3|    625    |
| 627 |name_3|    626    |
| 628 |name_4|    627    |
```

Comment: Pls show your query

Answer (score 0):

You can use two statements in a single query

```
INSERT INTO routes(name) values('name')

UPDATE routes set master_id = (select max(id) from routes) 
where id = (select max(id) from routes)
```

First, it will insert a new row with an incremented `id` then it will update `master_id` with `max(id)`

**Update**
According to your latest update in the queston, first, you need to insert a row out foreach loop and get its last inserted id through php and then update that row  there. Then in the loop add insert query with that last inserted id that you have got previously in the `master_id` column. That's it

Comment: let me try to implement it

Comment: is it possible to have only the first last_inserted_id to all master_id, means like this first table in my post, cause currently this method giving me same result like the wrong one i make now. @Zain Farooq

Comment: First `last_inserted` of all the time or for current occurrence?

Comment: Can you explain how this answer gives you the wrong result?

Comment: this code works fine in different condition, actually what I wanna do is get only the first id value then insert it into the rest data in column master_id like i show at first table @Zain Farooq

Comment: Updated my asnwer